# give a value to input when move then save it by ajax - php / jquery -php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a shopping cart and i'm almost finish. I use ajax for dynamic search and ajax for add to cart and use jquery for refresh a specific div when click but i face a problem.My problem is Quantity problem. I use session for store value 
//this is my session update code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" , "","atest");
session_start();
    require("functions.php");
    cart_session();
$id=$_POST['id'];
        //echo $arr['cart'];

        if(isset($_SESSION[$arr["cart"]][$id])){

            $_SESSION[$arr["cart"]][$id][$arr["quantity"]]++;
            //redirect("http://localhost/my/work/sellingcart/index.php",true);

        }else{

            $sql_s="SELECT * FROM product_1
                WHERE p_id={$id}";
            //echo $sql_s;
            $query_s=mysqli_query($con,$sql_s);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_s)!=0){
                $row_s=mysqli_fetch_array($query_s);

                $_SESSION[$arr['cart']][$row_s["p_id"]]=array(
            "{$arr["quantity"]}" => 1
                    );

                //redirect("http://localhost/my/work/sellingcart/index.php",true);
            }else{

                $message="This product id it's invalid!";

            }

        }
```

//use ajax for update cart

```
 <script>     
      $("#link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $("#id").val(); 

  var dataString = 'id='+id;
    $('#loading-image').show();
$(".form :input").attr("disabled", true);
$('#remove_cart').hide();
$('#link').hide();
 $(".container").css({"opacity":".3"}); 


$(".form :input").attr("disabled", true);
$('#remove_cart').hide();
$('#link').hide();
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url:'add_cart.php',
    success:function(data) {
      $('#availability').html(data);  
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#loading-image').hide();
        $(".form :input").attr("disabled", false);
        $('#remove_cart').show();
        $('#link').show();
        $(".container").css({"opacity":"1"}); 


    }
  });
//$("#chat").load(location.href + " #chat");
//$("#chat").load(location.href+" #chat>*","");
});


 </script>
```

[image]
Here is image and Red mark is my problem.

i want to update my cart when i give value and move it then it update my session by ajax and php.

Is there any help? I don't want to user can update there quantity every cart item singly. i want it dynamic just give quantity number and move then it save by ajax.

Comment: no there is no problem. i complete it. but main problem is update quantity.

Comment: i just need a way to when i give value to quantity suppose 10 then i need to click update button i just want to remove all update button for all carting product just want to give a value to quantity when i click to other area then it save the value without refresh using ajax

Comment: I wrestled a bear once. thanks you but arr not define but its define to another file its a large file.
please help me on thing . quantity give and move then it save with ajax . 
in now you just give quantity and need to click update for each quantity but its boring for anyone

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to assign an onchange event on the quantity input boxes. On change in value of a quantity input box, you need to send an AJAX request which already seems to be handled in your php.

Comment: Yes Nvj . Is there any way ? No need to see my code. Just there is a quantity box and i just give 10 and move then ajax save it . but how its possible any short code?? Give me some simple instruction then i can do it. my project is complete without quantity section ajax using but its not fully complete i need to change quantity with ajax too

Comment: without ajax it completed . but when i added ajax then i did first add cart . then when click add cart then ajax update session and jquery update customer_cart div. But i am struct in quantity. ajax not work for dynamic quantity. my project is 95% complete .

Comment: check out the code below .. does that work for you ?

Comment: waw nice work ... i really forget onchange... your giving code is very much helpfull to me .............. thank you .  Nvj . but its not complete yet but i try it soon if its complete then i will your answer as a right answer .
this is my array 
Array
(
    [1] (my product id) => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 20 (my product quantity)
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 1
        )

) 

and only quantity not work need to pass my product id with it.
onchange="save_quantity(<?php echo $row['p_id'] ?>)"
thank you so much

Comment: Yes you do need to pass product id with it.. I've added that to the code below. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: You add id but there are to many product can be add so what id need to change quantity? So id must passing in onchange function.. ok my work completed thanks to nvj.. really you remind me onchange can be use.. thats why i silve it. Sometime sity thing can make you suffer.. ok i give my question's answer in bellow... and its done. Now you want to know how its work out do you tell me what you want to know?? The processing or you want to see it in online?? Prosseing is : quantity has product id for each and that is unique. Then i catch product id and pass the onchange. So i know the product id.

Comment: Now i need to know the quantity value too so i just use qty_product id . So every qty name also be unique. So have pid and quantity so use ajax and in my php i match my session id with product id ..my session id is the product id its known to you and replace quantity.. done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127452/discussion-between-al-mahbub-khan-and-nvj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an onchange event to your quantity input boxes:

```
$('input[name=quantityBox]').change(function() { ... });
```

In your function() above, add an AJAX POST request containing something like

```
var quantity = $('input[name=quantityBox]').val();
// var id = something;
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:"productId=" + id + "&updateQuantity=" + quantity,
    url:'add_cart.php',
    success:function(data) {
        $('#availability').html(data);  
    },
    complete: function(){
        // anything you want to do on successful update of request
    }
});
```

In your PHP function above, you check whether the product already exists in user's cart. At that point, change the quantity.

```
 if(isset($_SESSION[$arr["cart"]][$id])){

        $quantity = $_POST['updateQuantity'];
        $id = $_POST['productId'];
        $_SESSION[$arr["cart"]][$id][$arr["quantity"]] = $quantity;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Special Thanks To Nvj

Assign an onchange event to your quantity input boxes:

```
<input id="qty<?php echo $row['p_id'] ?>" value="" onchange="save_quantity(<?php echo $row['p_id'] ?>)">
```

function  with ajax :

```
function save_quantity(x){
        var quantity=$("#qty"+x).val();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:"updateQuantity=" + quantity+ "&id="+x,
            url:'update_qty.php',
            success:function(data) {
                $('#availability').html(data);  
            },
            complete: function(){
                // anything you want to do on successful update of request
            }
        });

}
```

php file update_qty.php

```
    session_start();
 $qty = $_POST["updateQuantity"];
 $p_id = $_POST["id"];

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
                        if($id==$p_id)
                        echo $id;
                        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']=$qty;
                    }
```